# Android Bluetooth A2dp sink for Bluetooth Speaker

Tags: android, bluetooth, frameworks, android-bluetooth, a2dp

I'm making Bluetooth speaker with android device. from android to android.

I'm searching for a lot of information for this. but there is no answer to satisfy.

I want to make android 8.0 device as a2dp sink.

I can modify Android Framework.

I already change in config.xml but it doesn't work.

Could you let me know about this problem?

Comment: hey, do you found anything useful? I'm also working on the same type of application. If you found anything useful please share.